# Factory girl Timestamps issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I was using the following code to generate 3 mocks:

```
  # today is 27.02
  order1 = Factory(:order, :created_at => Date.yesterday) # created_all is 25.02?
  order2 = Factory(:order, :quantity => 2, :created_at => Date.today) # created_all is 26.02??
  order3 = Factory(:order, :created_at => Date.today) # created_all is 26.02???
```

In order to have the date set right I use:

```
  order1 = Factory(:order, :created_at => 1.days.ago)
  order2 = Factory(:order, :quantity => 2, :created_at => Time.now)
  order3 = Factory(:order, :created_at => Time.now)
```

Any idea what is the diffrence betwen Date.today and Time.now ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First they are instances of different classes, and represent different info:
Date contains only date information, and Time contains all the date, time, and timezone info

```
>> Date.today
 => #<Date: 2012-02-27 (4911969/2,0,2299161)> 
>> Time.now
 => 2012-02-27 14:14:22 +0200
```

In your example both Date.today and Time.now will be type-casted to the type you have in db (date or time)

```
>> Time.now
 => 2012-02-27 14:14:22 +0200 
>> Time.now.to_date
 => #<Date: 2012-02-27 (4911969/2,0,2299161)> 
>> Time.now.to_date.to_time
 => 2012-02-27 00:00:00 +0200
```